# 'expanded' literature search questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm wondering what the community thinks of questions that look to fill gaps/expand literature on a particular topic.

The stimulus for this post is a question seeking in-depth literature on a particular (well-defined) topic.

The fact that the scope of the topic is defined is positive. However, what about the 'listiness' of the question?

Also see related question [here](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/54/131) by @selene.

Answer (score 2):

I agree these questions might be a bit problematic, also because the "best" answer will likely change over time (if a complete answer is possible at all). Will it always have the most recent literature? Will it be updated regularly?

I think a community wiki might be a good approach!

Answer (score 1):

The 'listiness' of the question is a bit bothering.

The slightly bothersome part is that a 'listy' question, esp. a literature related one is unlikely to be have a complete answer. Maybe we should consider making all literature search based answers to a 'listy' question into a community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the earlier discussion on using wikis ([here](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-to-decide-when-a-topic-question-should-be-made-into-a-community-wiki)), I think our community would benefit from waiting to convert questions to wiki until we reach the public beta phase.

Two goals of Private Beta are to (1) create a solid foundation of high quality Q&A prior to going public and (2) allow our users to participate, earn reputation points, and earn/use moderation tools.

Assuming we are able to graduate to Public Beta, perhaps one of our tasks at that point will be to identify questions appropriate for wiki (and perhaps clean them up a little!).